# Make a text field unique in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Here I am trying to make the mobile number field unique (original code):

```php
if (!empty(trim($value[13]))) {
    $contact_array['mobile'] = $value[13];
} else {
    $is_valid =  false;
    $error_msg = "Mobile number is not unique";
    break;
}
```

I am new to Laravel, I tried this and surely it didn't worked:

```php
if (!empty(trim($value[13]))) {
    $contact_array['mobile'] = $value[13]&&unique:contacts,mobile;
} else {
    $is_valid =  false;
    $error_msg = "Mobile number is not unique";
    break;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that is just straight-up invalid PHP syntax. Follow the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#manually-creating-validators, https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique

Answer (score 1):

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'mobile' => 'required|unique:contacts',
    ]);
    $contact = new Contact();
    $contact ->mobile= $request->mobile;
    $contact ->save();
    Toastr::success('Contact Successfully Save','Success');
    return redirect()->route('admin.contact .index');
}
```